# Slow performance while opening applications

Tags: performance

I moved from Win 8.1 64bit to Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with a fresh install from DVD. Everything is moving slow with performance. Graphics is fair, but when I say performance I mean, an average to open any application, I can count to 10 Mississippi before it loads i.e. firefox, LibreOffice, Chrome, etc. System tools take roughly 5 seconds. Login takes about 25 seconds. Boot time is great at about less than 20 seconds. Any ideas?

Here is my configuration:

```
description: Desktop Computer
product: MS-7253 ()
vendor: MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO., LTD
version: 1.0
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop
discrete graphics: NVIDIA  GT218 [GeForce 210]
```

> core
>          Motherboard
>   product: MS-7253
>   vendor: MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO., LTD
>   physical id: 0
>          version: 1.0

```
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Phoenix Technologies, LTD
      physical id: 0
      version: V1.8
      date: 03/06/2008
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 448KiB
      capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 7
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+
      slot: Socket AM2
      size: 2200MHz
      capacity: 3GHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 200MHz
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy
    *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: b
         slot: Internal Cache
         size: 128KiB
         capacity: 128KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: c
         slot: External Cache
         size: 512KiB
         capacity: 512KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 19
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 2GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM
         product: None
         vendor: None
         physical id: 0
         serial: None
         slot: A0
         size: 1GiB
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM
         product: None
         vendor: None
         physical id: 1
         serial: None
         slot: A1
         size: 1GiB
         width: 64 bits
 *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8M890CE Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=agpgart-amd64 latency=8
      resources: irq:0 memory:0-7ffffff
    *-generic UNCLAIMED
         description: PIC
         product: K8M890CE I/O APIC Interrupt Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 0.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:00.5
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: io_x_-apic bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: VT8237/8251 PCI bridge [K8M890/K8T800/K8T890 South]
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:dfc00000-dfcfffff memory:dfb00000-dfbfffff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: K8T890 PCI to PCI Bridge Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress pm msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:27 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:dd000000-deffffff ioport:b0000000(size=536870912)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: a2
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
            resources: irq:24 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:df00(size=128) memory:c0000000-c007ffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: High Definition Audio Controller
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
            version: a1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:25 memory:deffc000-deffffff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: K8T890 PCI to PCI Bridge Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress pm msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:31 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:dfe00000-dfefffff ioport:dfd00000(size=1048576)
    *-ide:0
         description: IDE interface
         product: VT8237A SATA 2-Port Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
         version: 80
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=sata_via latency=64
         resources: irq:21 ioport:ff00(size=8) ioport:fe00(size=4) ioport:fd00(size=8) ioport:fc00(size=4) ioport:fb00(size=16) ioport:f400(size=256)
    *-ide:1
         description: IDE interface
         product: VT82C586A/B/VT82C686/A/B/VT823x/A/C PIPC Bus Master IDE
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: f.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.1
         version: 07
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pata_via latency=64
         resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:fa00(size=16)
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 10
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
         version: a0
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=64
         resources: irq:20 ioport:f900(size=32)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 10.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.1
         version: a0
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=64
         resources: irq:22 ioport:f800(size=32)
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 10.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.2
         version: a0
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=64
         resources: irq:21 ioport:f700(size=32)
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 10.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.3
         version: a0
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=64
         resources: irq:23 ioport:f600(size=32)
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: USB 2.0
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 10.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:10.4
         version: 86
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=64
         resources: irq:21 memory:dffff000-dffff0ff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: VT8237A PCI to ISA Bridge
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa pm cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: VT6102 [Rhine-II]
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 12
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 7c
         serial: ea:49:f3:0f:4c:e0
         size: 10Mbit/s
         capacity: 100Mbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=via-rhine driverversion=1.5.1 duplex=half latency=64 link=no maxlatency=8 mingnt=3 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
         resources: irq:23 ioport:f200(size=256) memory:dfffe000-dfffe0ff
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: VT8237A PCI to PCI Bridge
         vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
         physical id: 13.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci ht subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
         resources: ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:dfa00000-dfafffff ioport:df900000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY
            vendor: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp
            physical id: 4
            bus info: pci@0000:04:04.0
            logical name: eth1
            version: 31
            serial: 00:08:54:e0:9f:78
            size: 100Mbit/s
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sundance driverversion=1.2 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.9 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=10 mingnt=10 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
            resources: irq:17 ioport:bf00(size=128) memory:dfaff000-dfaff1ff memory:df900000-df90ffff
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8M890CE Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.1
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8M890CE Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8M890CE Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.3
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8M890CE Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.4
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8M890CE Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.7
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:6
      description: Host bridge
      product: VT8237/8251 Ultra VLINK Controller
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 106
      bus info: pci@0000:00:11.7
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: latency=64
 *-pci:7
      description: Host bridge
      product: VT8237A Host Bridge
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 107
      bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:8
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 108
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:9
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 109
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:10
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 10a
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:11
      description: Host bridge
      product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 10b
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=k8temp
      resources: irq:0
 *-multimedia
      description: Audio device
      product: VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller
      vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: pci@0000:80:01.0
      version: 10
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
      resources: irq:17 memory:afffc000-afffffff
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi2
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk:0
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC WD1600AB-22D
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 15.0
         serial: WD-WCAEK1160784
         size: 149GiB (160GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0005cb4f
       *-volume:0
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: 3cec4927-961e-4dc9-be15-fac612a854b0
            size: 147GiB
            capacity: 147GiB
            capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2014-05-19 20:40:13 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2014-05-21 10:37:15 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2014-05-21 10:37:15 state=mounted
       *-volume:1
            description: Extended partition
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            size: 2045MiB
            capacity: 2045MiB
            capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
          *-logicalvolume
               description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
               physical id: 5
               logical name: /dev/sda5
               capacity: 2045MiB
               capabilities: nofs
    *-disk:1
         description: ATA Disk
         product: ST3120020A
         vendor: Seagate
         physical id: 0.1.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.1.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: 3.31
         serial: 3KA1SJZX
         size: 111GiB (120GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=4b36adea
       *-volume
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@2:0.1.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sdb1
            version: 3.1
            serial: 160bc649-fff3-a04c-ad93-8f7430e55541
            size: 111GiB
            capacity: 111GiB
            capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-02-26 17:14:57 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 3
      logical name: scsi3
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom:0
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVDRW SHM-165H6S
         vendor: LITE-ON
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         logical name: /media/juan/NSA320
         version: HS0D
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
            logical name: /media/juan/NSA320
            configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted
    *-cdrom:1
         description: DVD writer
         product: DVD+-RW DVD8801
         vendor: PHILIPS
         physical id: 0.1.0
         bus info: scsi@3:0.1.0
         logical name: /dev/sr1
         version: 2D06
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
 *-scsi:2
      physical id: 4
      bus info: usb@1:4
      logical name: scsi4
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdc
         size: 2007MiB (2104MB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=759f2192
       *-volume
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: MSDOS5.0
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sdc1
            logical name: /media/juan/DO NOT USE
            version: FAT16
            serial: aa43-9db8
            size: 1899MiB
            capacity: 1900MiB
            capabilities: primary fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
 *-scsi:3
      physical id: 5
      bus info: usb@5:1
      logical name: scsi5
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk:0
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdd
         configuration: sectorsize=512
    *-disk:1
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.1
         bus info: scsi@5:0.0.1
         logical name: /dev/sde
         configuration: sectorsize=512
    *-disk:2
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.2
         bus info: scsi@5:0.0.2
         logical name: /dev/sdf
         configuration: sectorsize=512
    *-disk:3
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.3
         bus info: scsi@5:0.0.3
         logical name: /dev/sdg
         configuration: sectorsize=512
```

Comment: Do this happened with the live session?

Comment: Had about the same problem with 14.04
Saw another tip: replace Firefox with Google Chrome
And it took care of "all" performance problems
Try it

Comment: I tried chrome and it still was slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by reinstalling with 32-bit OS

Answer (score 0):

as I see you have only 2GB ram as that right ok verify that you instal ubuntu 32 bit not 64 bit

if you do that may be your problem from video card like it may be old to run high graphic that found in unity or have problem in drivers for it like you must use proprietary driver not open source for your vga or opposite

so try that two from devices manager settings if same problem still found and you tried all solution above so try to install light Desktop Environment which haven't graphics like lxde or lighter that it

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

log in to this DE in see if you still feel slow or not

Comment: I will try installing 32bit as I have 64bit installed. I will return with my results

Comment: ok and I think may be that is your problem install any os 64 bit only if you have at least 4g ram or higher we'll wait you

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud20070

Reinstalling to 32bit resolve my performance issue. All performance time were cut in half!!